# Exponential growth one-liner function fails on one test but not others?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions, one-liner

Can anyone debug this for me? I've been staring at it and testing things for hours but can't seem to get it working. I'm starting to wonder whether the coding challenge web app is wrong and I'm right!

The task is this:

> Find the number of generations it would take for a population `p0` to surpass a max population `p` given that the population increases by `percent`% plus `aug` every generation

My one-liner is as follows:

```
nbYear = (p0, percent, aug, p) => {
  return Array(999).fill().filter((_,i)=>Array(i+1).fill().map((_,j)=>j==0?p0:0).reduce((y,_)=>Math.round(y*percent/100+y+aug))<=p).length;
}
```

The code I've written passes on 100 tests but fails on one in particular (they don't disclose the input paramters on which it failed). All it says is that the function gave the output: `51` when it should have been `50`

Comment: That kind of thing is unreadable. Space it out onto multiple lines and it'll be much easier to understand and debug.

Comment: Well it certainly fails for values above 999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've concluded that the one test for which it failed must have been for a value over 999.